# Slow SQL query involving CONTAINS and OR

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

We’re having a problem we were hoping the good folks of Stack Overflow could help us with. We’re running SQL Server 2008 R2 and are having problems with a query that takes a very long time to run on a moderate set of data , about 100000 rows. We're using CONTAINS to search through xml files and LIKE on another column to support leading wild cards.

We’ve reproduced the problem with the following small query that takes about 35 seconds to run:

```
SELECT something FROM table1 
WHERE (CONTAINS(TextColumn, '"WhatEver"') OR  
        DescriptionColumn LIKE '%WhatEver%')
```

Query plan:

[image: Slow query]

If we modify the query above to using UNION instead, the running time drops from 35 seconds to < 1 seconds. We would like to avoid using this approach to solve the issue.

```
SELECT something FROM table1 WHERE (CONTAINS(TextColumn, '"WhatEver"') 
UNION
(SELECT something FROM table1 WHERE (DescriptionColumn LIKE '%WhatEver%'))
```

Query plan:

[image: Fast query]

The column that we’re using CONTAINS to search through is a column with type image and consists of xml files sized anywhere from 1k to 20k in size.

We have no good theories as to why the first query is so slow so we were hoping someone here would have something wise to say on the matter. The query plans don’t show anything out of the ordinary as far as we can tell. We've also rebuilt the indexes and statistics.

Is there anything blatantly obvious we’re overlooking here?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Have you tried changing the order of the where clauses?

Comment: Yes, we have already tried this. There were no measurable differences in performance.

Comment: Can you run seperately the two queries? Which is slower?

Comment: Can we see the two query plan ? And how much rows are returned by each query ?

Comment: Do the two versions produce different execution plans?

Comment: The queries run so fast on their own that its difficult to get good readings on what query is slower.

Comment: The execution plans have now been added to the original post

Comment: The CONTAINS query returns 5 entries while the LIKE returns 0

Comment: Are your table statistics up to date?

Comment: Yes. They are up to date

Comment: You forgot to mention the patch level of your Sql Server. It's probably 10.00.2531

Comment: I have the same issue. Adding an `OR` clause causes the server to **scan** the **entire** table, rather than doing the correct thing.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using `DescriptionColumn LIKE '%WhatEver%'` instead of `CONTAINS(DescriptionColumn, '"WhatEver"')`?

`CONTAINS` is obviously a Full-Text predicate and will use the SQL Server Full-Text engine to filter the search results, however `LIKE` is a "normal" SQL Server keyword and so SQL Server will not use the Full-Text engine to asist with this query - In this case because the `LIKE` term begins with a wildcard SQL Server will be unable to use any indexes to help with the query either which will most likely result in a table scan and / or poorer performance than using the Full-Text engine.

Its <strike>difficult</strike> impossible to tell without an execution plan, however my guess on whats happening would be:

- The `UNION` variation of the query is performing a table scan against `table1` - the table scan is not fast, however because there are relatively few rows in the table it is not performing *that* slowly (compared to a 35s benchmark).
- In the `OR` variation of the query SQL Server is first using the Full-Text engine to filter based on the `CONTAINS` and then goes on to perform an RDI lookup on each matching row in the result to filter based on the `LIKE` predicate, however for some reason SQL Server has massively underestimated the number of rows (this can happen with certain types of predicate) and so goes on to perform several thousnad RDI lookups which ends up being incredibly slow (a table scan would have been much quicker).

To really understand whats going on you need to get a query plan.

Comment: The reason we are using LIKE to search the "DescriptionColumn" is to allow leading wildcards when searching. I apologize for not mentioning this in the original question. The query plans have been added to the original post.

Comment: The `LIKE` is the original query is not relevant to the issue. You can instead `OR SomeNumberColumnCoveredByAnIndex = 69` and the performance still falls over dead. The fact that it's doing a clustered index scan is no because `DescriptionColumn` is being queries with `%value%`; the server switches to a clustered index scan as soon as the `OR` appears - even with a numeric column covered by an index querying for single value equality (e.g. `DescriptionID = 7`)

Answer (score 1):

Did you guys try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE CONTAINS((column1, column2, column3), '"*keyword*"')
```

Instead of this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE CONTAINS(column1, '"*keyword*"') 
OR CONTAINS(column2, '"*keyword*"') 
OR CONTAINS(column3y, '"*keyword*"')
```

The first one is a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this. This is reportedly a bug on SQL server 2008 R2:

http://www.arcomit.co.uk/support/kb.aspx?kbid=000060

Your approach of using a UNION of two selects instead of an OR is the workaround they recommend in that article.